# How to set cookies in Scrapy+Splash when javascript makes multiple requests?

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

When the javascript is loaded, it makes a another ajax request where cookies should be set in the response. However, Splash does not keep any cookies across multiple requests, is there a way to keep the cookies across all requests? Or even assign them manually between each requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is an example in [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) README - see [Session Handling](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash#session-handling) section. In short, first, make sure that all settings are correct. Then use `SplashRequest(url, endpoint='execute', args={'lua_source': script})` to send scrapy requests. Rendering script should be like this:

```
function main(splash)
    splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)

    -- ... your script

    return {
        cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
        -- ... other results, e.g. html
    }
end
```

There is also a complete example with cookie handling, header handling, etc. in scrapy-splash README - see a last example [here](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash#examples).

Comment: Thanks for the help Mikhail, what happens when I need to set cookies for calls made in the javascript, 4 different requests happen when i do `splash:go(url)`, I would like to set cookies after the second request

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the question. Cookies received in AJAX responses should be merged to Splash cookiejar and returned in splash:get_cookies(). splash:init_cookies() sets content of a browser cookiejar, browser should use these cookies for all requests, including AJAX requests. So the script above should work regardless of how many requests you're making in your Lua script.

Comment: Oh I understand now, so I guess the problem is not with the cookies. I'm basically trying to access Crunchbase.com through Splash, they have some weird bot protection. Accessing from a browser always works. Do you have any idea of how to make Splash's behavior exactly like a browser's?

Comment: Splash works like a browser, but a rather old one; it uses almost the same rendering engine as PhantomJS 2.0 - it is WebKit from 2013. It is possible to detect this engine using e.g. engine-specific bugs and gotchas, or using its missing features. It also sets user agent which can be identified (you can set your own though).

Comment: I see, appreciate your help!